# Run Time error in making kusto connection in c# -- AADSTS50079:

Tags: c#, adal, azure-data-explorer

"Run time exception  AADSTS50079: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must enroll in multi-factor authentication"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var builder = new 
  KustoConnectionStringBuilder("help.kusto.windows.net/Samples")
     {
        FederatedSecurity = true,
        UserID = "***@microsoft.com",
        Password = "****",
        EnforceMfa = true
     };

     var client = 
     Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(builder); 
     var reader = client.ExecuteQuery("StormEvents | count");

    }
```

Comment: According to the error, it may be caused by [Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-conditional-access-developer). For more details, please refer to https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/troubleshooting-mfa.

Comment: If so, you can try to close the policy to solve the issue or try to use the following code ```var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder($"https://{serviceNameAndRegion}.kusto.windows.net")
{
    FederatedSecurity = true,
    InitialCatalog = "NetDefaultDB",
    Authority = authority,
};```. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/connection-strings/kusto#aad-based-authentication-examples

Answer (score 0):

If you are microsoft FTE and try to query kusto on a dotNet Core Console Application, I suggest you to use a dotNet Framework Console Application.
use

```
var client = Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider("https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples;Fed=true");
var reader = client.ExecuteQuery("MyTable | count");
// Read the first row from reader -- it's 0'th column is the count of records in MyTable
// Don't forget to dispose of reader when done.
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-data 
Then it will pop up a window to use VSTS as a multi-factor authentication.
It seems that VSTS authentication not support dotNet Core.