# azure aks with terraform gives me error Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create an aks cluster with Terraform. [Here are the config files for the same](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureAksTerraform/tree/main/iac/010050-basic-aks). Validation went well. But plan gives the following error.

Got some experience with Terraform as well as azure and aks, but not with Azure Ad. So enlighten whats going wrong.

Looked into [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59254410/1977871) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61113914/1977871) as well, but no clue.

```
Error: building account: getting authenticated object ID: parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: AADSTS50076: Due to 
a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.
│ Trace ID: 3391ac9b-4e8d-43a3-88f5-0cb1093a2d00
│ Correlation ID: fe984fa6-71ff-42d6-b487-7b988a7e1dd6
│ Timestamp: 2022-08-23 13:39:59Z
│ To re-authenticate, please run:
│ az login --scope https://graph.microsoft.com//.default
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on tf1-provider.tf line 48, in provider "azurerm":
│   48: provider "azurerm" {
```

[image: Terraform error when creating azure aks]

az login is already done (below, ids removed).

[image: az login]

### Update

It turns out its something to do with az auth. When I ran

```
az ad sp list --all
```

I got exactly the same message.

Then I ran

```
az login --scope https://graph.microsoft.com//.default
```

as suggested. Then it asked me to run

```
az login --tenant <tenantId>
```

And this time it logged me in after two factor(mobile OTP). Then finally this error went away.

Did not understand fully, but thats how I resolved it for now.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure AD error AADSTS50076 is thrown whenever [MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks) is required. In order to prompt MFA you need to re-authenticate interactively which is what you just did.

If you were not facing this issue before it's because MFA was not enabled or was not required but now it is. You will need to reach the a tenant admin to get more information about such setup.

For more information about Azure AD errors take a look to [Azure AD Authentication and authorization error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes).